# Either equal or not overlapped

Tags: c, optimization, restrict-qualifier

Let's say a function that add two vectors

```
void add256(int* r, int* p, int* q) {
    for (int i=0; i<256; ++i) {
        r[i] = p[i] + q[i];
    }
}
```

Now if I know `r` is either `p` or not in the same array with `p`, and same to `q`, can `restrict` help optimize the code with parallel add instruction?

---

I asked this question because, on GCC,

```
typedef struct { int x[256]; } int256;
void add256t(int256* r, int256* p, int256* q) {
    for (int i=0; i<256; ++i) {
        r->x[i] = p->x[i] + q->x[i];
    }
}
```

can be optimized with the exactly assumed conditions and to my intended asm, but separating in different situation makes code a mess and asm separated situation doing same thing

Comment: Can you reword your question to make it clearer? If you'd have `void add256(int* restrict r, int* p, int* q)` for example, you're ensuring the compiler that the object pointed to by `r` is not aliased by any other pointer (since you are modifying it). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict

Comment: @gst Yet it's possible that `r==p`, in which case it's still possible to parallel

Comment: are they’re pointing to the same address or do they just contain the same values? If they’re pointing to the same address, using restrict will lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `restrict`, you make a promise to the compiler. Breaking that promise leads to undefined behavior.

The way I interpret your question is that the pointers are either the same or does not overlap at all. In that case, you can optimize like this:

```
void add256_rEQp(int restrict *r, int restrict *q) {
    for (int i=0; i<256; ++i) {
        r[i] += q[i];
    }
}

void add256(int* r, int* p, int* q) {
    if(r == p && r != q)
        add_256rEQp(r, q);
    else if( ...
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<256; ++i) {
            r[i] = p[i] + q[i];
        }
    }
}
```

But of course, you should run tests to see if it improves performance. After all, this does introduce a bit of overhead.

Comment: If I write https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7XWFrJ , I get the correct code. It's likely that GCC always generate correct code in such situation, but IIRC it's UB, and I want to know a better way

Comment: @l4m2 `void add256(int256& r, int256& p, int256& q)` is not C. It's C++.

Comment: Same in C https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KlD7bf language doesn't matter much